# How would I get this function to display a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
string_one = "this is string one"
string_two = "this is string two"

def choose_number():
    if radio_value.get() == 'One':
        number = string_one
    elif radio_value.get() == 'Two':
        numbers = string_two

    print numbers
```

I'm trying to display the numbers variable when the radio button is selected

If I run this code I get an error saying numbers is not defined. But if I place numbers in the function the second radio button wont work

Comment: Is the print statement supposed to be inside the `choose_number` function?

Comment: There is no class in the code you have shown us.

Comment: I meant to say function not class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

- `number = string_one` - you probably meant `numbers = string_one`
- `numbers` becomes not defined if `radio_value.get()` is not either `One` or `Two`. You need an `else`:

  ```
  def choose_number():
      if radio_value.get() == 'One':
          numbers = string_one
      elif radio_value.get() == 'Two':
          numbers = string_two
      else:
          numbers = 'Not Found'

      print numbers
  ```

Better define a dictionary mapping and use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with providing a default in case value wasn't found:

```
mapping = {'One': "this is string one",
           'Two': "this is string two"}

def choose_number():
    print mapping.get(radio_value.get(), 'Not Found')
```